# How can i get remaining part of string after numeric digits found

Tags: php

How can i get remaining part of string after numeric digits found.

> ex.1)  `hello12cool4here`
>
> output should be: `2cool4here`
>
> ex.2)  `hel3lo12cool4here`
>
> output should be: `lo12cool4here`

Comment: Detect first digit and then do a substr().

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO is not a free coding service. You have to show some effort in solving your problem. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Creating MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) also take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Add more cases. What if there is no digit in the string? Can strings start with first digit itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regexps:

```
preg_match('/^\D*\d(.*)/', 'hello12cool4here', $matches);
echo($matches[1]);    // 2cool4here
preg_match('/^\D*\d(.*)/', 'hel3lo12cool4here', $matches);
echo($matches[1]);    // lo12cool4here
preg_match('/^\D*\d(.*)/', '42lo12cool4here', $matches);
echo($matches[1]);    // 2lo12cool4here
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if the string is starting with a digit I believe, like `1hello12cool4here`.

Comment: @mitkosoft updated for such case.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over all the characters and test if they are numeric, return when first is found:

```
$str='hello12cool4here';

for( $i=0; $i< strlen( $str ); $i++ ){
    if( is_numeric( substr($str,$i,1) ) )exit( substr( $str, $i+1 ) );
}
```

Or putting that into a function:

```
function findremainder( $str ){
    for( $i=0; $i< strlen( $str ); $i++ ){
        if( is_numeric( substr($str,$i,1) ) )return( substr( $str, $i+1 ) );
    }
    return $str;
}


echo findremainder( $str );
```

Comment: Awesome. Working Exactly. Thank you.